# Assignation of string with accents to another string, replaces them with "&amp;#243;"

Tags: c#, string, non-ascii-characters

I have a list of elements, and one of those elements field is a string value that contains an spanish-accented text which I see ok in the list.
Once I enter de Detail page for one of those elements, the accents are shown like this `&#243;`

I have a string variable that contains the original Spanish-Accented text, and I assign that value to the new view.
Example:

```
string a = "facturación";

view.Document = a;
```

and the field a of the class view is declared like this:

```
string Document { get; set; }
```

when I do a quickwatch over "a" I see "facturación".

when I do a quickwatch over "view.Document" y see `"facturaci&amp;#243;n"`

what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of view is it?

Comment: it's an interface that inherits from IView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error!
The property was re-defined like this:

```
public string Document
  {
    get
    {
      return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtDocument.Text);
    }
    set
    {
      txtDocument.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);
    }
  }
```

So the HtmlEncoding was the thing that was messing up with my string.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that the view is escaping the string before rendering it. Use 
`<%= Server.HtmlDecode(mystring) %>` in your view to render the string un-escaped.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not an MVC view. I show the value in a asp:textbox